# FB.login response does not include authResponse

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, cordova-plugins

I am creating a Mobile application with facebook Login using the offcial phonegap plugin
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin
The problem is when I authenticate the application it return the response without the authentication response.

```
     FB.login(function(response) {

  alert(response.authResponse);
  alert("login:"+JSON.stringify(response));

            if (response.session) {
            alert('logged in');
          } else {
           alert('not logged in');
           }

            },
          { scope: "email" });
```

where the response is {"id":"12345677876","first_name":"xxxxx".........

Therefore "response.authResponse" is always **undefined**.

Comment: can't you use getLoginStatus. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Comment: Sounds to me like the FB.login method you are calling is not the one provided by the JS SDK, as that one does not expose first_name etc.

Comment: @SeanKinsey, you are right, I am using a custom one issued bye cordova